# can eclipse C/C++ IDE be used for java too?

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded .tar.gz  install file for C/C++ eclipse IDE.
Can it also be used for java or do I need additional ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is, you should install the right plugin - JDT (look at Help->Install new Software)

Answer (score 2):

Base on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) link:

> In computer programming, Eclipse is an integrated development
>   environment (IDE). It contains a base workspace and an extensible
>   plug-in system for customizing the environment.

That means Eclipse is just a platform, and you can install any plugins for eclipse.  On Eclipse site, you see some packages such as *Eclipse CDT* *Eclipse JDT* ... Because they just want you to have a convenient environment for working: just download and run. You can download any versions, and install **enough** other plugins and they will works well. Here is some tutorials: [official link](http://eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php) and [another nice link](http://www.cyberspice.org.uk/blog/2009/11/20/installing_eclipse_for_multiple_programming_languages/)

But my recommendation is:

1. you don't know how "enough" is (as newbie). So the result will be hard because you don't choose enough packages for supporting your languages. And Eclipse Foundation has made it for you.
2. You shouldn't use many languages in same Eclipse distribution (although you can switch to other *workspace* easily). Many languages mean many installed packages, and this will **slow down** your eclipse so much because eclipse must loads more plugins into memory, loads more projects ... This is my experience. So, each language, each eclipse distribution, each workspace. That's a trick.

And answering directly to your question:YES. You can use that version for programming java, but will need to install **JDT (Java Development Toolkit)** plugin.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the valuable information. Speed is very important (becuase I have limited resources anyway). In the bottom line, what did you actually suggest ? Do you mean that I should install another distribution just for JAVA programming environment  (instead of additional plugin) ? Thanks!

Comment: @ransh yes. You download Eclipse JDT for programming java, and Eclipse CDT for programming C++. Eclipse JDT will create a workspace name "java workspace" and eclipse CDT will create a workspace name "c++ workspace". (workspace name just example, you can name anything by your own). By this way, you will load eclipse fast and memory efficient. :)

Comment: Thanks very much , that's interesting. I did have bad past experience with eclipse in terms of speed in my virtual machine (I use laptop with virtualbox), and I moved to other lighter and speeder IDE, but now I unfortunately have to use eclipse again, so this is certainly very important to know.